# Prove Triple Composite Function's Inverse?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

How do we prove that when given function:

$D(x) = (a∘b∘c)(x)$

Its inverse is given as:

$D^{-1}(x) = (c^{-1}∘b^{-1}∘a^{-1})(x)$

Do we just plug in simple functions for a b c and d?

Comment: Surely you mean $(c^{-1}\circ b^{-1}\circ a^{-1})$ instead.

Comment: Forgot about that lol thanks

Comment: "*Do we just plug in simple functions...*" absolutely not.  Proof by example is not proof at all.  You will have shown that in one specific case out of infinitely many cases the proposition is true, but there are still infinitely many cases that you haven't yet checked.  To proceed, try computing $D\circ D^{-1}$ and computing $D^{-1}\circ D$ temporarily ignoring the notation implying that $D^{-1}$ is the functional inverse of $D$ and instead using $(c^{-1}\circ b^{-1}\circ a^{-1})$

Answer (score 0):

From
$D(x) = (a∘b∘c)(x)
$
and
$D^{-1}(x) = (c^{-1}∘b^{-1}∘a^{-1})(x)
$
we get

$\begin{array}\\
D^{-1}(D(x)) 
&= (c^{-1}∘b^{-1}∘a^{-1})(D(x))\\
&= (c^{-1}∘b^{-1}∘a^{-1})((a∘b∘c)(x))\\
&= (c^{-1}∘b^{-1}∘a^{-1}∘a∘b∘c)(x)\\
&= (c^{-1}∘b^{-1}∘(a^{-1}∘a)∘b∘c)(x)\\
&= (c^{-1}∘b^{-1}∘b∘c)(x)\\
&= (c^{-1}∘(b^{-1}∘b)∘c)(x)\\
&= (c^{-1}∘c)(x)\\
&= x\\
\end{array}
$

and the same holds for
$D(D^{-1}(x))$.

For a more pedestrian example,
the inverse of
putting on socks then putting on shoes
is
taking off shoes then taking off socks.